# Connect to LDAP via ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, active-directory

I am trying to get the following connection to our LDAP working via ColdFusion, however, I can never get it to return any values (i.e. results.recordcount always equals 0). I assume my problem is with the "start" portion of the query so I did some research and have tried numerous values but nothing seems to work.

```
<cfldap 
  server = "adserver" 
  action = "query" 
  username = "DOMAIN\username" 
  password = "apassword" 
  name = "results" 
  scope="subtree" 
  start = "dc=domain.local" 
  attributes = "givenname,surname,uid,userid,groupMembership,mail,dn,roles,memberof,cn,samaccountName">

<cfoutput>
  #results.recordcount#
</cfoutput>
```

The structure of the AD that I'm trying to access is as follows. I'm trying to get to the "Users" section at the bottom of the tree shown.

```
Active Directory Users and Computers
- Saved queries
- domain.local
  - option1
  - option2
  - NAME1
    - option1
    - option2
    - NAME2
      - Computers
      - Disabled Users
      - Groups
      - Users
```

If I right-click on "User" and view the properties it tells me the canonical name for it is domain.local/NAME1/NAME2/Users, which I assume is relevant to my problem.

Any ideas what I should be using for the "start" portion of cfldap?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I highly recommend browsing your AD with a program like Softerra's LDAP Browser (http://www.ldapbrowser.com/) and then locating the distinguished name of the hierarchy where you want to start searching. Using this, I was able to find the exact DN of the LDAP structure to target.

Comment: Thanks Ben. I have done as you suggested and the structure to where I want to go is ServerName->DC=name->OU=name2->OU=name3->OU->Users. I therefore updated my cfldap start attribute to be "start="DC=name,OU=name2,OU=name3,OU=Users" but this generates the following error: An error has occured while trying to execute query :[LDAP: error code 1 - 000020D6: SvcErr: DSID-031006CC, problem 5012 (DIR_ERROR), data 0 ]. Any ideas?

Comment: If I set start to just DC=name then the error goes away but I revert to the problem of getting zero results.

Comment: I've only implemented cfldap once before and using the LDAP Browser was an immense help. If you can't connect using that then you are using incorrect naming conventions (it took me way too long to figure it out)

Comment: I usually only get directory errors when there is a problem with my Start Path. I usually copy and paste it from LDAP Browser's right-click contextual menu and it was good. It did require a bit of trial-and-error until I got the tag to be happy.

Comment: Using Ben's suggestion above showed the start path needed to be the opposite of what I thought it should be. That is, instead of working from the top down (e.g. DC=local,DC=domain,OU=group,OU=Users), ldapbroswer's contextual menu showed that I actually needed to work from the bottom up (e.g. OU=Users,OU=group,DC=domain,DC=local). This is something I probably would have never thought to try so thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Try somethign like this.  I've had the best luck starting at a high level and then using the filter attribute to drill down.

```
<cfldap action="query" start="DC=server, DC=domain, DC=com" filter="OU=Users" 
username = "DOMAIN\username" password = "apassword" name = "results" 
scope="subtree" attributes = "givenname,surname,uid,userid,groupMembership,mail,dn,roles,memberof,cn,samaccountName">
```